# Ubuntu very slow startup

Tags: laptop, startup, performance, hp, 15.04

My new laptop is taking very long (a few minutes) until it reaches the log-in screen.

Here is the output of `dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/MuW79kVd

I think the important part is the following gap in the time:

```
[    6.861250] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
[    6.861304] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input21
[    6.861346] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input22
[    6.861391] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input23
[   66.332039] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   67.830294] usb 1-9: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   67.962114] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=1041
[   67.962117] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
```

It is an HP Probook 640 laptop. Here is some more information about the hardware (I am not sure what is important here).

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Does it run OK with Ubuntu **14.04 LTS**? *Did you add/remove any USB devices (eg. mouse), or where they present at power on?*

Comment: I did not try an earlier version, it is a new Laptop. The devices were all plugged in from the start. I will try to restart without having the mouse plugged in later.

Comment: Ok, so without the mouse plugged in the boot takes about 10 seconds, so at least I have this as a temporary fix. Plugging the mouse in after log-in works without problem. The message I get during booting with the mouse is "A start job is running for udev wait for complete device initialization".

Comment: This could be a driver issue, but I have only heard of similar issues with (inbuilt) touchpads. *That was related to interrupts and device conflicts, with new drivers for touch screens (so unrelated to what you have).*

Comment: Also try a different USB port, and/or check BIOS/setup for port hibernation / power saving.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you, but I had the same error you mention in a comment below your post and it was related to loading my built in bluetooth device.

> A start job is running for udev wait for complete device initialization

Followed by the USB disconnect message.

After a few reboots my syslog hinted to error -110 which is power related, this error did not show up during the first reboots.

I got it working again by shutting the computer down and disconnecting the power cord for a few seconds, after that the computer booted fast again and I got the Bluetooth device back.

Comment: As a side note, my computer is an Intel NUC and I suspect that the issue is related to connecting a WD Elements drive to one of the USB ports.